# v8: can't get calling function name in a functioncallback

Tags: v8

I want to make a log of every function called when i run a js script.
So i want to make a callback for all the functions in javascript like this:

```
global->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "print"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, LogName));
global->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "eval"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, LogName));
global->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "unescape"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, LogName));
```

I define my function like this:

```
void LogName(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
    v8::String::Utf8Value str_caller(args.Callee());   
    printf("%s", str_caller); 
}
```

This is printed when unescape is called: function unescape() { [native code] }

But if do:

```
object = v8::Handle<v8::Object>::Cast(context->Global()->Get(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "String")));
object->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "fromCharCode"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, LogName)->GetFunction());
```

This is printed when String.fromCharCode is called: function () { [native code] }

Why in the second example i don't have the functions name, like for example "fromCharCode" ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still pretty new to V8 but have run into this exact same problem. I've found only one solution so far. I'm not sure if it is ideal, but there are no other solutions so here goes...

Notice the functions where getting the name works are where you are adding a FunctionTemplate value to an ObjectTemplate (that is presumably then used as the global template parameter when you create the Context).  Also notice in the ones that don't work you are trying to add a Function to the global Object for that existing Context, and this is when getting the Callee name fails (returns a blank string).

The only solution I've found so far is to keep a persistent handle to the ObjectTemplate you create for global scope, add the FunctionTemplate to that when you go to register your new function, and then create a new Context that uses that modified ObjectTemplate. After this then calls to the function will return the Callee name as desired.

To try to illustrate this with some code:

```
Isolate *gIsolate;
Persistent<ObjectTemplate> gTemplate;
Persistent<Context> gContext;

// Adds a new function to the global object template
void AddFunction(const char *name, FunctionCallback func)
{
    // Get global template
    Local<ObjectTemplate> global = ObjectTemplate::New(gIsolate, gTemplate);

    // Add new function to it
    global->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(gIsolate, name), FunctionTemplate::New(gIsolate, func));
}

void FirstTimeInit()
{
    gIsolate = Isolate::New();
    HandleScope handle_scope(gIsolate);
    Handle<ObjectTemplate> global = ObjectTemplate::New(gIsolate);

    // Store global template in persistent handle
    gTemplate.Reset(gIsolate, global);

    // Register starting functions
    AddFunction( "print", LogName );
    AddFunction( "eval", LogName );
    AddFunction( "unescape", LogName );

    // Create context
    Handle<Context> context = Context::New(gIsolate, NULL, global);

    gContext.Reset(gIsolate, context);
}

void AddOtherFunction()
{
    AddFunction( "fromCharCode", LogName );

    Local<ObjectTemplate> global = ObjectTemplate::New(gIsolate, gTemplate);

    // Create a new context from the modified global template
    Local<Context> newContext = Context::New(gIsolate, nil, global);

    // Update persistent context handle to reference the new one
    gContext.Reset(gIsolate, newContext);
}
```